# Overload a Function that accepts Any Number of Positional Arguments and returns int or Tuple[int]

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

I am trying to type hint a function that accepts any number of positional arguments and returns int if size is 1 and returns tuple of same size if it is more than 1.

This is what I have right now:

```py
def timestamp(*date: Union[datetime, str, int]) -> int | Tuple[int, ...]:
    """
    It converts a date to a timestamp

    :param date: The date to be converted to timestamp
    :return: The number of seconds since the epoch.
    """
    if len(date) == 1: return timestamp_(date[0])
    return tuple([timestamp_(d) for d in date])
```

mypy does not complain about this, but I want to overload it in a correct way because it will be a little bit hard to use this function with correct types

Comment: Django use `flat=True` to return element instead of tuple: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: Why even provide this functionality? Just write a function that works on a single argument, and if the caller needs to call it for more than one, it's a trivial listcomp?

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with [`@typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload). See live demonstration at [mypy Playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=0d93a91ca18f4c7f43c3694ab28a409f) (used with mypy 1.7.1 and Python 3.12.1).

```py
import typing as t
from datetime import datetime

@t.overload
def timestamp(date: datetime | str | int, /) -> int:  # type: ignore[overload-overlap]
    """
    Handles the situation where only 1 positional argument is passed in
    
    Note: `# type: ignore[<mypy error code>]` may change depending on the mypy
    version you're running.
    """

@t.overload
def timestamp(*date: datetime | str | int) -> tuple[int, ...]:
    """
    Handles the situation where 0, 2, or more position arguments are
    passed in.
    """

def timestamp(*date: datetime | str | int) -> int | tuple[int, ...]:
    """Implementation"""
```

```
>>> reveal_type(timestamp(0))     # Revealed type is "builtins.int"
>>> reveal_type(timestamp(0, 0))  # Revealed type is "builtins.tuple[builtins.int, ...]""
```

The core idea behind `@typing.overload` is to sequentially provide an order of function signatures which can be checked one-by-one to find compatibility between the argument(s) to the signature. Once a compatible signature has been found, the return type associated with that signature will be inferred for that set of arguments.

Since Python does not have a way of expressing "0 or 2+ variadic positional arguments, but not 1", you need to make a higher-priority overload which takes exactly 1 argument, followed by a lower-priority overload which takes an arbitrary number of arguments. The suppressed error code basically indicates that the overload for 1 argument can be handled with the overload with multiple arguments. We suppress it because **we never want to infer the overload with multiple arguments when we only pass 1 argument**.

Answer (score 0):

An example with `flat` kwarg:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Literal, overload


def timestamp_(d) -> int:
    return 1


@overload
def timestamp(*date: datetime | str | int, flat: Literal[True]) -> int:
    ...


@overload
def timestamp(
    *date: datetime | str | int, flat: Literal[False] = False
) -> tuple[int, ...]:
    ...


def timestamp(*date: datetime | str | int, flat=False) -> int | tuple[int, ...]:
    """
    It converts a date to a timestamp

    :param date: The date to be converted to timestamp
    :return: The number of seconds since the epoch.
    """
    if flat:
        if len(date) == 1:
            return timestamp_(date[0])
        else:
            raise ValueError
    return tuple([timestamp_(d) for d in date])


def main():
    print(f"{timestamp(1) = }")
    print(f"{timestamp(1, flat=True) = }")
    print(f"{timestamp(1, 2) = }")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
timestamp(1) = (1,)
timestamp(1, flat=True) = 1
timestamp(1, 2) = (1, 1)
```

Comment: hmmm interesting approach but it means that I can not achieve that without adding any additional parameters right?

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. I think it is better to use additional parameters.